# Make changes to a list of strings within a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

I have a list that looks like this `["first letter", " second letter", " third letter"]`In some cases, the first character is an empty character " ". In these cases, I want to strip off the first character and modify my list to become like this:

```
["first letter", "second letter", "third letter"]
```

How can I achieve this? This doesnt work because I am not modifying the string itself and there can be more than 1 " " characters in each string. I only want to remove the first.

```
    for i in setOfCoordinates:
        if i[0] == ' ':
            print('space found')
            i.replace(" ", "")
```

I don't want to remove all spaces, just the first one

Comment: ```for i in setOfCoordinates:```. You are already iterating over the elements of the list. Fetching ```i[0]``` will fetch the first character of the **element**. Replace ```i[0]``` with ```i```

Comment: `test = [i.lstrip() for i in setOfCoordinates]` removes all spaces also. :)

Comment: That is intentional. I want to fetch the first character and check if its an empty character. If its empty, then I want to strip it off @Sujay

Comment: I don't want to remove all spaces, just the first one @user56700

Comment: [i.lstrip() for i in a] should do the job

Comment: @x89 changed comment to use left strip `.lstrip` unless you mean you only want to check the first index of the list?

Comment: would this only work when there's a space in the beginning or will it remove the first character of all elements? @user56700

Comment: @x89 all elements of the list.

Comment: but I don't want it to work for the first element for example, where there's no space in the beginning @user56700

Comment: @x89 then i think the answer from Sujay would help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
my =  ["first letter", " second letter", " third letter"]
for i in range(0,len(my),1):
    if my[i][0] == " " :
        my[i] = my[i][1:]
print(my)

# result : ['first letter', 'second letter', 'third letter']
```

I used the 'for' function. After that, through 'Slice', the string was truncated if the front was blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use `enumerate`. Also, `replace` is **not** an in place function. It will return the replaced string. So, you can use string concatenation. `i[0]+i[1:]` which concatenate the string.

```
l=["first letter", " second letter", " third letter"]
for j,i in enumerate(l):
    if i[0]==" ":
        print("Space found")
        l[j]=i[0].replace(" ",'')+i[1:]
        print("Space removed")
print(l)
```

Output:

```
Space found
Space removed
Space found
Space removed
['first letter', 'second letter', 'third letter']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `str.lremoveprefix()` if you want to remove the first space but not the spaces after the letters. See more info on https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

```
setOfCoordinates = [" first letter", "  second letter  ", "   third letter   "]
print(setOfCoordinates) #[' first letter', '  second letter  ', '   third letter   ']
setOfCoordinates = [i.removeprefix(" ") for i in setOfCoordinates]
print(setOfCoordinates) #['first letter', ' second letter  ', '  third letter   ']
```

Comment: but doesn't modify the original list

Comment: @x89 code is now updated and now modify the original list

Comment: `lstrip` strips all leading spaces, not just one

Comment: @SevC_10, my bad, its `str.removeprefix()` we are looking for here. Updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `count` parameter of the `replace` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

In your case:

```
i.replace(" ", "", 1)
```

just replaces 1 occurrence of `" "`

In order to modify the strings in the list, use their index *(credit to @Sujay answer)*:

```
l = ["first letter", " second letter", " third letter"]
for j, i in enumerate(l):
    if i[0] == " ":
        print("Space found")
        l[j] = l[j].replace(" ", "",1)
print(l)
```

Comment: but if the first char isn't a space, it would remove the middle space, no?

Comment: In that case yes, but first you check if the first character is a space, then apply the `replace`

Answer (score -1):

```
x = ["first letter", " second letter", " third letter"]
x = [i.strip() for i in x] #### remove space from both the ends
print(x)
```

##### removing space from the start

```
x = ["first letter", " second letter", " third letter"]
x = [i.lstrip() for i in x]
print(x)
```

##### removing space from end

```
x = ["first letter", " second letter", " third letter"]
x = [i.rstrip() for i in x] #### remove space from both the ends
print(x)
```

Comment: `strip` functions remove all trailing or leading spaces, not just one

Comment: That's why I have shown for all. Whichever he wants to use can use it.